# Multiple UIViews per tab in UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am wondering if there is a way I can have multiple ui views per tab in my UITabBarController.

As an example, let's say I have 3 tabs. Dashboard, Info, and Feedback. The use case I want to be able to do is click on Info and click on a button in that initial view that allows me to segue to another UI View. I can do this, but the problem is I lose the tab bar on the bottom. Is there a way I can maintain the tab bar yet still segue to another UIView down the line? It's important to me that I maintain the UITabBar because I need to be able to go to any of the other tabs at any given time and access the data that was left in each individual tab.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `UINavigationController` for your tab bar tab and set its `rootViewController` to your first view controller. And create a push segue from from button that is in your first view controller to second view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Mind your terms. You mean multiple view CONTROLLERS per tab in a tab bar controller. Views and view controllers are not interchangeable, and you should never call a view controller a view. It leads to confusion.

As the other poster suggested, have each tab in your tab bar controller contain a navigation controller. Then you can push additional view controllers onto the navigation controller and the tab bar will remain.

If you want to host multiple view controllers on the same window in a tab you can use container views and embed segues.